# Given three points, find the arc length of a section between two intersecting lines.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I have three points, one being the center, and the other two are end points on a line drawn to the center. I need an equation that provides $\Theta$. In this drawing $(x_1, y_1)$ is the center.

[image: Artist's depiction]

Comment: Don't forget to vote up the answer

Comment: Wish I could, but my measly reputation of 3 won't allow me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m_1 =  \frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$

$m_2 =  \frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$

Now the angle $\theta$ between the lines

$\tan \theta = |\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}|$

Now arc length $\Theta = r\theta $

where r = radius of circle.